# parallax refreshing the page not taking the page to the landing page

Tags: parallax

I am very much new to the scripting languages...

While my queries are mentioned below:

I am working on a parallax website : http://sysconnect.co.in/clematis/

But I want that if the person refreshes the page from the inner page it must bring the page back to the landing page....

I have used the below code on the page but it still not functioning as required...

Since, after refreshing twice then the page moves to the landing page...

Could some one help me to get it right?

```
jQuery('body').scrollTop(0);
jQuery(window).scrollTop(0);
jQuery('html').scrollTop(0);
window.scrollTo(0,0);
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you try:

```
document.getElementById("body").scrollTop = 0;
```

If this doesn't work, you may want to replace the "body" element id with the id of the container of your parallax section.

If you need parallax-specific scrolling help, my company and I have a list of parallax tutorials at http://potentpages.com/parallax-tutorials/. You will likely want the [jQuery section](http://potentpages.com/parallax-tutorials/#jQuery). A tutorial there may be able to help you if the "scrollTop" solution doesn't work.